# Time difference between some actions in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe of members of a site and action they have done in specific time from time =0 :

```
import pandas as pd
times = [21 , 34, 37, 40, 55, 65, 67, 84, 88, 90 , 91, 97, 104,105, 108]
names = ['bob', 'alice', 'bob', 'bob', 'ali', 'alice', 'bob', 'ali', 'moji', 'ali', 'moji', 'ali', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob']
actions = ['enter', 'enter', 'search', 'search', 'enter', 'search', 'purchase', 'exit', 'enter' , 'enter', 'search', 'purchase', 'exit', 'enter', 'purchase']
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : names , 'action': actions, 'time' : times})
```

I want to do calculation between two arbitrary action, for example,
time difference between enter and purchase by each user, and so in this example I want the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['bob', 'ali', 'bob'], 'enter_to_purchase_time' : [46 , 7,3]})
```

How could I do such a calculation neatly in Python?
(If it is possible I prefer to don't add many columns to my dataframe because may be somewhere I have dataframe by so many actions and also may I change the two actions between them I do calculation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `pandasql` as it greatly facilitates set processing.

Using SQL also makes it easier to share solutions and increases readability for the large community familiar with SQL.

If you are looking for the time between the most recent entry and purchase for each name, proceed as follows:

```
import pandasql as ps

enter_to_purchase_time = ps.sqldf("""
    SELECT distinct p.name, 
    min(p.time) over (partition by p.name, p.time order by p.time) - 
    max(e.time) over (partition by e.name, p.time order by e.time desc) time_to_purchase
    FROM df p
    inner join df e
     on e.name = p.name 
    where  p.action='purchase'
     and e.action='enter'
     and e.time < p.time
    order by e.time  """, locals())


print(enter_to_purchase_time)
```

```
name  time_to_purchase
0  bob                46
1  ali                 7
2  bob                 3
```

If you're looking for the time elapsed until each purchase a user makes from the first time he/she entered, the following SQL will work:

```
enter_to_purchase_time = ps.sqldf("""
    SELECT distinct p.name, 
    min(p.time) over (partition by p.name, p.time order by p.time) - 
    min(e.time) over (partition by e.name, p.time order by e.time) time_to_purchase
    FROM df p
    inner join df e
     on e.name = p.name 
    where  p.action='purchase'
     and e.action='enter'
     order by e.time  """, locals())

print(enter_to_purchase_time)
```

Which returns

```
  name  time_to_purchase
0  bob                46
1  bob                87
2  ali                42
```

Comment: `1  bob -38` how time is negative?

Comment: @deadshot: I have updated the SQL so that it only returns the time between the first purchase and entry time by name.

Comment: @LarsSkaug I don't understand your numbers. ali entered at time 90 and purchased at time 97 and so I want 97-90 = 7 and name of ali next to it.

Comment: @moshtaba: Ali entered first at 55, so 97 - 55 = 42. I will update the answer to reflect the latest entry time as an alternative.

Comment: @LarsSkaug Your solution is exactly what I want. But I'm not familiar with SQL. Could you refer me to a MINIMAL introduction to QSL by which I could understand all details of your code?

Comment: @moshtaba: If you prefer video tutorials, I'd say this is pretty good: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql As for books, it's hard to pass up Ben Forta’s “Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes"

Answer (score 1):

Try with `cumsum` and do the subgroupby key, then we do `groupby` with `np.ptp`

```
df['new'] = df.action.eq('purchase').iloc[::-1].groupby(df.name).cumsum()
df = df.drop_duplicates(['name','action','new'],keep='last')
s = df.loc[df.action.isin(['enter','purchase'])].groupby(['name','new'])['time'].agg(np.ptp)
s
Out[118]: 
name   new
ali    1.0     7
alice  0.0     0
bob    1.0     3
       2.0    46
Name: time, dtype: int64
```